# My program prints a lot of blank lines when there should be none

Tags: java, loops, printing

I have this small program which I have been working on, which is supposed to ask the user for a name, which it prints 100 times, and then it will ask whether or not the sure will give another name and do it again. This works for me, however; when I am queried for whether or not I want to do it again, it prints a lot of blank lines, can anyone give me a tip as to why this happens?

```
import java.util.*;

class Uke44{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean lokke=true;

        while(lokke){

            System.out.println("Vennligst oppgi navn: ");
            String navn=input.nextLine();   

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println(navn);
            }

            System.out.println("Gi et nytt navn? j/n: ");
            char valg = input.next().charAt(0);

            if(valg=='j'){
                System.out.println("Vennligst oppgi navn: "); //The problem must lie around here I think.
                navn=input.nextLine();  

                for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println(navn);
                }

            }else{
                lokke=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char valg = input.next().charAt(0);
```

change this to

```
char valg = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

because when you give `j` and hit enter, the `navn=input.nextLine();` inside the `if` is consuming that keystroke and assigning your `navn` with it. This `navn` is now printed 100 times again which is what you think as *a lot of blank lines*.

Comment: You get correct answer for today, as this was the real problem with my code, and you solved it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You have a duplicate 100-times bucle that does the same.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        System.out.println(navn);
    }
```

so, if after the first one, you select 'j' it will print navn 200 times, one for the second bucle and another time when entering again from `while(lokke)`

To solve your problem, remove the second bucle, your code will show:

```
import java.util.*;

class Uke44{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean lokke=true;

        while(lokke){

            System.out.println("Vennligst oppgi navn: ");
            String navn=input.nextLine();   

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println(navn);
            }

            System.out.println("Gi et nytt navn? j/n: ");
            char valg = input.next().charAt(0);

            if(valg!='j'){
                lokke=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't actually help. I tried some debugging (I know, I should have done that first but thought I did yesterday. Obviously not.) It does go the start of the while-loop and everything is done correctly, but the problem is now: It asks for the name again, but it doesn't wait for user input! It asks the user, fills it with blank spaces before user is able to input anything and then asks again, doing it over again. So the error must be at 
String navn=input.nextLine();?

Comment: @Makri - Check out my answer! It addresses this very problem of yours.

Comment: is bucle supposed to be loop?